# I am using Lombok in a Spring project but Maven build fails

Tags: java, spring, maven, lombok

I want to add Lombok to my Spring project. I'm using  I use Maven, so I put the lombok dependency on my pom.xml file.
Here is the dependency part of my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <!-- scope>test</scope-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java/sonar-jacoco-listeners -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I try to run maven with "mvn clean install", the build fails and I can't find the reason. Here is the log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project-management 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ project-management ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/domingosmartins/git/switch-2017-g003/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ project-management ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/domingosmartins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/domingosmartins/git/switch-2017-g003/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ project-management ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ project-management ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 138 source files to /Users/domingosmartins/git/switch-2017-g003/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] No processor claimed any of these annotations: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping,org.springframework.stereotype.Controller,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody,javax.persistence.Table,org.springframework.stereotype.Service,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore,javax.persistence.Enumerated,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler,org.springframework.stereotype.Repository,javax.persistence.ManyToMany,javax.persistence.Id,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice,javax.persistence.Entity,javax.persistence.ManyToOne,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication,javax.transaction.Transactional,javax.persistence.JoinColumn,javax.persistence.OneToMany,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController,javax.persistence.OneToOne,javax.persistence.Column,org.springframework.stereotype.Component,javax.persistence.GeneratedValue,javax.persistence.Transient,javax.annotation.PostConstruct,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
[INFO] 1 warning
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] warnings found and -Werror specified
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.878 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-10T15:16:57+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/294M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project project-management: Compilation failure
[ERROR] warnings found and -Werror specified
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I'm using IntelliJ and had already checked "Enable annotation processing" (Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors).

When I run mvn clean install -e:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project-management 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ project-management ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/domingosmartins/git/switch-2017-g003/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ project-management ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/domingosmartins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/domingosmartins/git/switch-2017-g003/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ project-management ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ project-management ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 138 source files to /Users/domingosmartins/git/switch-2017-g003/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] No processor claimed any of these annotations: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping,org.springframework.stereotype.Controller,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody,javax.persistence.Table,org.springframework.stereotype.Service,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore,javax.persistence.Enumerated,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler,org.springframework.stereotype.Repository,javax.persistence.ManyToMany,javax.persistence.Id,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice,javax.persistence.Entity,javax.persistence.ManyToOne,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication,javax.transaction.Transactional,javax.persistence.JoinColumn,javax.persistence.OneToMany,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController,javax.persistence.OneToOne,javax.persistence.Column,org.springframework.stereotype.Component,javax.persistence.GeneratedValue,javax.persistence.Transient,javax.annotation.PostConstruct,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
[INFO] 1 warning
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] warnings found and -Werror specified
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.603 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-12T01:06:27+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/288M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project project-management: Compilation failure
[ERROR] warnings found and -Werror specified
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project project-management: Compilation failure
warnings found and -Werror specified

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
warnings found and -Werror specified

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: What is your parent pom?

Comment: You can try putting maven into debug to see if it prints out any more info. Add the command line option `-X`. Have you installed the Lombok IntelliJ plugin?

Comment: `To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.`  can you re run and show the stacktrace.

Comment: The failure shows that it is not a problem of lombok your problem is Spring Boot...cause you wrote Spring project but the dependencies shows you are using spring boot ?

Comment: please add the full POM. Esp the plugin section.

Comment: @mavriksc I added the full stack above

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk I just have this parent pom

Comment: @Michael I have the plugin installed.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, the compiler plugin is configured to treat warnings as errors, either disable the annotation processor warning or configure it to not treat warnings as errors. 
Posting the rest of the pom would be useful, the dependencies dont matter much.

Comment: If those annotations don't get processed the app wont function at all. In the IDE do you see the dependencies? also to run the app do `mvn spring-boot:run` or to build a jar do `mvn package`

Comment: Is related to this [issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1339).

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at this line

```
[WARNING] No processor claimed any of these annotations: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping,org.springframework.stereotype.Controller,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody,javax.persistence.Table,org.springframework.stereotype.Service,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore,javax.persistence.Enumerated,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler,org.springframework.stereotype.Repository,javax.persistence.ManyToMany,javax.persistence.Id,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice,javax.persistence.Entity,javax.persistence.ManyToOne,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication,javax.transaction.Transactional,javax.persistence.JoinColumn,javax.persistence.OneToMany,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController,javax.persistence.OneToOne,javax.persistence.Column,org.springframework.stereotype.Component,javax.persistence.GeneratedValue,javax.persistence.Transient,javax.annotation.PostConstruct,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference
```

You need more starters to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

This is the pom.xml from a project that I mantain, copy pasted from my GitHub:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.lorescianatico</groupId>
<artifactId>driftcoin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>driftcoin</name>
<description>Driftcoin project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see, Lombok is declared as a optional dependency, with no scope or version. The parent pom is the Spring boot parent one. The parent pom contains all settings for handling Lombok.